# How to reliably detect DNS failure in ajax in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns

When DNS failure happen the error from jQuery ajax method is called with

```
 jxhr.status == 0 && jxhr.statusText == 'error'
```

is it reliable to set message to "DNS Failure" when this happen or is it better way to detect DNS error using AJAX?

Comment: Yes you can because status 0 comes when your server haven't receive your request.